# Shell - How to remove a particular string after nth occurrence of pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file which has pipe delimited data and i want to remove this string "EES" after 17th occurrence of pipe and write the data back to same file again

Below is the input i want to pass

```
AMC|FRS|M|123456|01/30/1992|QWERT||WERTYU|OK|USA|74000|1234567|QQ|34567142|11/01/2011|12/31/9999|Y|V3EES|13
```

below is the output i'm expecting

```
AMC|FRS|M|123456|01/30/1992|QWERT||WERTYU|OK|USA|74000|1234567|QQ|34567142|11/01/2011|12/31/9999|Y|V3|13
```

Help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk should help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" '{sub("EES","",$18)} 1' OFS="|"   Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Making here field separator as `|`(pipe) as per OP's Input_file then using awk's substitute utility sub where I am mentioning that replace string EES with NULL in column 18. Now mentioning 1 which will print the lines(edited/non-edited 18th column). Setting OFS(Output field separator as |(pipe)) here to get | in output, then mentioning the Input_file.

Comment: Thank you so much @RavinderSingh13, i'm almost there, as i'av asked, how do i write it back to the same file? currently executing this prints desired output on the screen while file remains unchanged, and doing this is deleting the entire contents in the file

awk -F"|" '{sub("EES","",$18)} 1' OFS="|" Input_file > Input_file

Comment: @Kiran Kumar, Done see my update now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, it works like charm, appreciate your help.

Comment: On the same note how do we remove EES from below input file
{"last_name":"Kiran","first_name":"kumar","sno":"1234","effective_date":"11/01/2011","cancel_date":"12/31/9999","alt_ein_id_indicator":"Y","alt_ein_id_employer_number":"V3EES"}

it comes after 7th colon (:) if this helps, i'av tried tweaking above command, but i failed

Comment: @KiranKumar, sorry but this isn't proper way to ask a question(even it is slightly different), please open a new post and let me know the link, could discuss overthere.

Comment: New to here, please excuse, sure thing!! @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Here's it 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546483/shell-how-to-remove-a-string-ees-from-a-record-after-7th-occurrence-of-colon

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {sub("EES","",$18); print}'  file
```

Using `grep` & `awk`

```
egrep -o "[A-Z0-9a-z]*" file | awk '{if(NR==18){sub("EES","")}printf("%s|",$0)}'
```