# Shell - How to remove a string "EES" from a record after 7th occurrence of colon(:)

Tags: shell, awk, sed

how do we remove EES from below input file

```
{"last_name":"Kiran","first_name":"kumar","sno":"1234","effe‌​ctive_date":"11/01/2‌​011","cancel_date":"‌​12/31/9999","alt_ein‌​_id_indicator":"Y","‌​alt_ein_id_employer_‌​number":"V3EES"}
```

Expecting the file after transformation to look like this

```
{"last_name":"Kiran","first_name":"kumar","sno":"1234","effe‌​ctive_date":"11/01/2‌​011","cancel_date":"‌​12/31/9999","alt_ein‌​_id_indicator":"Y","‌​alt_ein_id_employer_‌​number":"V3"}
```

TIA

Comment: Please do not post question in hurry, please use code tags for sample Input and expected sample output. We all are here for learning.

Comment: @Kiran Kumar, what is the criteria to remove ESS?

Comment: You asked VERY SIMILAR question some time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544223/shell-how-to-remove-a-particular-string-after-nth-occurrence-of-pipe

Comment: @PS., OP told there are some other conditions in OP's question so I requested to post a new question if it is too different.

Comment: As and when it gets to see a string by this name EES if present after 7th colon, it should be removed, not expecting that to be deleted anywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following awk should remove the EES string from 8th field or after 7th colon.

```
awk -F':' '{sub("EES","",$8)} 1' OFS=":"   Input_file
```

Will add a detailed explanation for same too shortly.

**Explanation:**

***awk -F':'*** Means I am setting up field separator here, by default in awk field separator's value is space so I am setting into colon now. So it will break the lines in parts with respect to colon only.

***{sub("EES","",$8)}*** Means, I am using substitute utility of awk, which will work on method sub(regex_to_be_subsituted,new_value,current_line/variable). So here I am giving string EES to be substituted with NULL("") in $8 means 8th field of the line(which you mentioned after 7th colon).

***1*** means, awk works on method of condition then action, so by writing 1 I am making condition TRUE and didn't mention any action, so by default print will happen.

***OFS=":"*** Means, setting output field separator, by default OFS will be space so as per your Input_file I am setting it to :

***Input_file*** Means, simply mentioning Input_file name here.

If you want to save output into same Input_file then following may help you.

```
awk -F':' '{sub("EES","",$8)} 1' OFS=":"   Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: Crisp explanation, worked for me, thanks @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for parsing JSON data

```
jq -c '.alt_ein_id_employer_number |= sub("EES";"")' file.json
```

```
{"last_name":"Kiran","first_name":"kumar","sno":"1234","effective_date":"11/01/2011","cancel_date":"12/31/9999","alt_ein_id_indicator":"Y","alt_ein_id_employer_number":"V3"}
```